# PropertyGrid not working?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, propertygrid, .net-4.5.2

I have this class and I'd like it to be editable by means of a PropertyGrid control.

```
Class ConfigurationValues
    Public UpdateCapital As Boolean = False
    Public verbosity As VerbosityLevel = VerbosityLevel.e0_StrategyInformation
    Enum VerbosityLevel
        e0_StrategyInformation
        e1_HighLevel
        e2_BaseRoutines
        e3_Confirmations
        e4_AlmostAll
        e5_EveryThing
    End Enum
End Class
```

This is my form.

```
    Public Class Form1
        Dim config As New ConfigurationValues
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = config
        End Sub
    End Class
```

The problem here, is that the PropertyGrid stays blank.

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: I think the members should be Properties not fields.

Comment: Yeah, I've figured by myself. Should I delete the question?

Comment: You could leave it here for others to fine, and continue to be helpful to the community.

Comment: Maybe someone comes with a msdn-style article about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PropertyGrid looks for properties. I also changed the Enum to be more readable - your choice though.

```
Public Class ConfigurationValues
  Public Property UpdateCapital As Boolean = False
  Public Property verbosity As VerbosityLevel = VerbosityLevel.StrategyInformation
  Public Enum VerbosityLevel
    StrategyInformation
    HighLevel
    BaseRoutines
    Confirmations
    AlmostAll
    EveryThing
  End Enum
End Class
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx)

[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3397/Bending-the-NET-PropertyGrid-to-Your-Will)

Comment: Sure may help someone else =)

Comment: Nope, I took the strange naming convention out since it makes it more readable code

Comment: That part is up to you

Comment: I added some great links also

Comment: You have to correct the code so that `Public Property verbosity As VerbosityLevel = VerbosityLevel.e0_StrategyInformation` becomes `Public Property verbosity As VerbosityLevel = VerbosityLevel.StrategyInformation`.